# issue in getting facebook profile data in android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-facebook

I have developed an application that have Facebook login facility through Facebook sdk and I am tacking user profile data like user name, id, location, profile image, birthday, email id so I got all data but getting issue while get profile image path so what is wrong in my code

**Code**:

```
mAsyncRunner.request("me", new AsyncFacebookRunner.RequestListener() {
   @Override
   public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
      Log.d("Profile", response);
      String json = response;
      try {
          JSONObject profile = new JSONObject(json);
          final String name = profile.getString("name");
          final String sex = profile.getString("gender");
          final String id = profile.getString("id");
          final String email = profile.getString("email");
          final String location = profile.getJSONObject("location").getString("name");
          final String birthday = profile.getString("birthday");
          final String picture = profile.getString("picture");

          Log.i("=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-",name+ "-------"+sex+"---------" +id+"---------"+email+"---------"+location+"---------"+birthday+"---------"+picture +"---------");
      } catch (JSONException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
}
```

getting error :--
org.json.JSONException: No value for picture

Comment: Do you mean that, you are not getting `picture`?

Comment: yes i didnt get responce of picture

Answer (score 0):

To get the `picture` url, you dont need to fetch this from the Graph API (I dont think `picture` field is valid), you can anytime use this url-

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{user-id}/picture
```

Check out [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/picture/) doc for more info.

So just remove this line from your code (since `picture` key does not exist in json)-

```
final String picture = profile.getString("picture");
```

To get the Bitmap-

```
URL imgUrl = new URL("http://graph.facebook.com/{user-id}/picture?type=large");
InputStream in = (InputStream) imgUrl.getContent();
Bitmap  bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
```

**Edit:**

If specifically needed the *Image url* (not recommended and not required yet)-

```
final String picture = 
        profile.getJSONObject("picture").getJSONObject("data").getString("url");
```

Comment: org.json.JSONException: No value for picture

Comment: You didnt got me. `https://graph.facebook.com/{user-id}/picture` thats the url of profile pictue that's it! You dont need any json nothing!

Comment: lol, that's what I'm saying you again and again that it is the image url only (it auto redirects to profile pic automatically)- see : http://graph.facebook.com/sahilmittal/picture

Comment: i want to get this url and store in database {
  "id": "1573711670", 
  "name": "Pranav Lathigara", 
  "picture": {
    "data": {
      "is_silhouette": false, 
      "url": "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-prn2/t5.0-1/1115737_1573711670_1739728801_q.jpg"
    }
  }
}

Comment: You should not! what if facebook changes the image store? If still you want to I'll add how to, check the edit

Comment: Then, i can get anything with that URL, like if i want username then i can get username with https://graph.facebook.com/{user-id}/username?

Comment: @PranavPatel, no! Its just meant for profile picture. For other details you need to have the access token